# Getfirstweek monday in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have following data:

```
date          |weekno
1/1/2015      | 1
1/2/2015      | 1
1/3/2015      | 1
1/1/2014      | 1
1/1/2014      | 1
1/2/2014      | 1
1/3/2014      | 1
1/4/2014      | 1
1/4/2015      | 2
1/5/2015      | 2
1/6/2015      | 2
1/7/2015      | 2
1/8/2015      | 2
1/9/2015      | 2
1/10/2015     | 2
```

based on this I tried below query

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECt 
    Date, 
    Weekno ,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WEEKno, YEAR(date) ORDER BY date ASC) AS RN
  FROM 
    dateinfo
)
select
  a.Date,
  a.Weekno,
  CAST(a.WEEKno AS VARCHAR) + '  ' +
    convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,a.Date),0),110) 
    as Firstdayofweeknodate
FROM 
  dateinfo AS A
  JOIN CTE AS B
    ON A.WEEKno=B.Weekno AND
    YEAR(A.Date)=YEAR(B.Date)
WHERE 
  B.RN = 1
```

it gives following output:

```
Date           |Weekno  |Firstdayofweeknodate
    2014-01-01  |1  |1  12-30-2013
    2014-01-02  |1  |1  12-30-2013
    2014-01-03  |1  |1  12-30-2013
    2014-01-04  |1  |1  12-30-2013
    2015-01-01  |1  |1  12-29-2014
    2015-01-02  |1  |1  12-29-2014
    2015-01-03  |1  |1  12-29-2014
    2015-01-04  |2  |2  01-05-2015
    2015-01-05  |2  |2  01-05-2015
    2015-01-06  |2  |2  01-05-2015
    2015-01-07  |2  |2  01-05-2015
    2015-01-08  |2  |2  01-05-2015
    2015-01-09  |2  |2  01-05-2015
    2015-01-10  |2  |2  01-05-2015
```

I want output like below:

```
Date        |Weekno |Firstdayofweeknodate
2014-01-01  |1  |1  01-01-2014
2014-01-02  |1  |1  01-01-2014
2014-01-03  |1  |1  01-01-2014
2014-01-04  |1  |1  01-01-2014
2015-01-01  |1  |1  01-01-2015
2015-01-02  |1  |1  01-01-2015
2015-01-03  |1  |1  01-01-2015
2015-01-04  |2  |2  01-05-2015
2015-01-05  |2  |2  01-05-2015
2015-01-06  |2  |2  01-05-2015
2015-01-07  |2  |2  01-05-2015
2015-01-08  |2  |2  01-05-2015
2015-01-09  |2  |2  01-05-2015
2015-01-10  |2  |2  01-05-2015
```

Comment: Why all these tags ? Aren't these supposed to be used when a question concerns a specific version ? That doesn't seem the case, so maybe you can remove these.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a syntax you could use:

```
SET datefirst 7

SELECT d,
  cast(case when datepart(week, d) = 1 THEN dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, d), 0)
  ELSE dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, d), -1) END as date) first_day_of_week, 
  datepart(week, d) week
FROM 
  (values
    ('2013-12-31'),('2014-12-31'),
    ('2014-01-01'),('2014-01-02'),
    ('2014-01-03'),('2014-01-04'),
    ('2014-01-05'),('2015-01-03'),
    ('2015-01-04'),('2015-01-05'),
    ('2015-01-06'),('2015-01-07'),
    ('2015-01-08'),('2015-01-09'),
    ('2015-01-10'),('2015-01-11')
  ) x(d)
```

Result:

```
d           first_day_of_week  week
2013-12-31  2013-12-29         53
2014-12-31  2014-12-28         53
2014-01-01  2014-01-01         1
2014-01-02  2014-01-01         1
2014-01-03  2014-01-01         1
2014-01-04  2014-01-01         1
2014-01-05  2014-01-05         2
2015-01-03  2015-01-01         1
2015-01-04  2015-01-04         2
2015-01-05  2015-01-04         2
2015-01-06  2015-01-04         2
2015-01-07  2015-01-04         2
2015-01-08  2015-01-04         2
2015-01-09  2015-01-04         2
2015-01-10  2015-01-04         2
2015-01-11  2015-01-11         3
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for providing query its working few off years as per my requirement if first week off any year having monday then we will display mondaydate for first week. if first week off days  of any year donot have monday  then we will display firstday off first week.above query working few off years but coming  1984 and 1985 years off first week display date not working.

Comment: here few off  first week year data look like below
StandardDate |Week 
1/1/1984 |1 
1/2/1984 |1 
1/3/1984 |1 
1/4/1984 |1 
1/5/1984 |1 
1/6/1984 |1 
1/7/1984 |1 
based on this above data we want dispaly like below
StandardDate |Week |first_dayoff_week
1/1/1984 |1 |1/2/1984
1/2/1984 |1 |1/2/1984
1/3/1984 |1 |1/2/1984
1/4/1984 |1 |1/2/1984
1/5/1984 |1 |1/2/1984
1/6/1984 |1 |1/2/1984
1/7/1984 |1 |1/2/1984

remain years working fine to provide above query.please tell me how to achive this in sql server.

Comment: @user3457912 i tested those dates using my script. I got exactly what I expected. How is this wrong ? Can you edit your question to include those dates and expected outcome ?

Comment: Here mainly any weekno have monday then need to display  monday related date entire for that week.if weekno donot have monday day then display firstday off date its applicable for all years off weeks